# how to bind animation object to field in blackberry?

Tags: animation, blackberry, field

I am making an application in blackberry.But i am    not getting how to bind any animation to particular field? Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What does "bind" mean in your question? It is possible to make a custom field and implement animation.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761185/blackberry-how-to-animate-custom-field)