# Filp animation in blackberry Field

Tags: blackberry

I want to create a custom Field to show news. I have 20 news headlines, but only one will be visible. The field will have a timer that will change the new headline every 3 seconds. Creating a timer task is fine. But the real problem is, the animation while the headline change. I want to create a flip animation. How to do flip animation on the field?

I have used screen transition. But that does animation for the entire screen. But my requirement is to flip a screen widget.

Looking to develop for 5.x and above.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no transition for fields, so you could use third party code or write it yourself. You could find more insights here:

1. https://www.nloko.ca/blog/2010/11/blackberry-animated/
2. [Blackberry - fields layout animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497073/blackberry-fields-layout-animation)
3. [Blackberry - how to animate Custom Field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761185/blackberry-how-to-animate-custom-field)